# How to use "a bit long since..."?

Tags: tense

I am confused with the tense, I think

> It's a bit long since I last uploaded.

is probably OK (example [here](http://lifehacker.com/5950258/last-time-reminds-you-how-long-its-been-since-you-did-something-important)), but since there is a "since", shouldn't it be

> It's a bit long since I **had** last uploaded.

? Is **had** necessarily? But without it it seems an grammar error to me but still sounds good.

Comment: "It's a bit long since I last uploaded" is OK, although "[a little while](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+bit+long%2Ca+little+while&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20bit%20long%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20little%20while%3B%2Cc0)" is a more common locution: "It's a little while since I last uploaded."

Comment: How about "It's been long since I last uploaded."?

Comment: "It's been a long time since I last uploaded."

Comment: "It's a bit long since I last uploaded" is OK?? It really isn't OK. ///It's been a while since I last uploaded anything. In other words, some amount of time has gone by since I last uploaded anything.

Answer (score 1):

> It's a bit long since I last uploaded.

is understandable, but to express duration of time

> It's been **a bit longer than** *(since)* my previous update.
>   *the time since my previous update and the one before that was shorter than my previous update and now*
>
> It's taken a **bit longer than** I anticipated.
>   *it has taken a little longer than I anticipated*

Which is different than a physical measurement

> The thread is a **bit long**.
>   *the thread is a little longer than I needed*

Answer (score 1):

- It's been a while since I last uploaded anything to [x].
- I haven't uploaded anything for a bit. [time]

Usually, bit goes at the end with this meaning: to have not done anything for a bit.

For time.